# Is there a difference between "starts" and "activates" for Eclipse RCP plugin?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

When creating a plugin, in the manifest file there's an option to "Activate this plug-in when one of its classes is loaded":

[image]

Also, when configuring a product, there's also option to specify plugin Start Levels:

[image]

Is the concept of "starting" the same or different than "activating". If they're different, how so?

Comment: Yes, the [_start_ method of the Activator](https://osgi.org/javadoc/osgi.core/7.0.0/org/osgi/framework/BundleActivator.html#start-org.osgi.framework.BundleContext-) is called when the plug-in/bundle is started (this is an OSGi thing on which Eclipse is based on).

Comment: There is a [very old blog post about the start level that still applies today](https://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2009/06/10/osgi-and-start-levels/) (please note, in OSGi plug-ins are called bundles).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start Levels are used to control the order in which plug-ins are started when Eclipse itself is starting up. This is necessary to ensure that some services are available when they are needed. The picture below shows the default start levels. At level 1 `org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator` is the plug-in that loads most of the other plug-ins - so it needs to start first!

[image: Default start levels]

'Activate this plug-in when one of its classes is loaded' is an option to control when the plug-in Activator class is called (if it has one). If this is specified the activator is not called until something needs to use one of the other classes in the plug-in.  If not specified the Activator will only be called if the plug-in is started by 'Auto-Start' in the start levels or an explicit OSGi start call.

Note that many plug-ins don't need an Activator at all.

Comment: A strange thing I notice is if I don't specify anything in this Start Levels section, then `org.eclipse.core.runtime` and some other plugins like in the picture will start on their own, but if I manually add one plugin in here then `org.eclipse.core.runtime` and others will not be added automatically, and I have to add them all manually for the app to start

Comment: Also, just to clarify: if `auto-start` is `true` here, then no matter whether `Activate this plug-in when one of its classes is loaded` is checked or not, then the plugin is always started, but if `auto-start` is `false` or no entry in here, then the plugin is only started if `Activate this plug-in when one of its classes is loaded` is checked AND one of its classes is loaded. Is that correct?

Comment: I think that is right, but finding good documentation on this is difficult.